# Scaling all images to console size XNA

Tags: c#, c, xna, sprite

The "game" I am trying to create has many buttons and images on the screen at once, and the buttons are designed for the base (what I believe to be 800x600) console size. The buttons and sprites are all in set positions.

The issue I am having is trying to get every image to scale when I do isfullscreen=true. The images stay in their relative position, but I need them to 'scale' based on the the actual size of the window.

While searching for an answer, I have found many that scale individual images or scale them based on the aspect ratio but what I am attempting to do is scale all images, no matter the aspect ratio, depending on the actual size of the XNA window. For example, If I have 3 100x60 sprites and 2 200x90 sprites placed on a 800x600 screen, how would I change the sprites to be the same relative size if the window size were to be changed to 1980x720 without having to manipulate each image?

Thanks

Edit: I've tried using a scale matrix, but that seems to require me setting the EXACT scale for that exact size, meaning I have to create a different scale matrix for each possible window size, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue i've been having using a ScaleMatrix, as I was using them incorrectly before.

Before, I was using a matrix of (800, 600) but now (I don't have access to the environment right now so it will have to be in pseudo) I have changed the code so its a variable scale:

(f)XScale = 800 / Viewport.Width

(f)Yscale = 600 / Viewport.Height

Matrix.createScale(XScale, YScale, 1 , 1)

I then passed this to the Spritebatch.Begin. The issue is, if you have something rendered to a triangle (Such as a background), then you may wish to render it in a different spritebatch.Begin as this scale will mess with the triangle.

I have a background rectangle and it applies the scale to it, which puts it off the screen. Its fine if it is something you wish to have scaled, such as a button rectangle.